# how to add version number in vim automatically?

Tags: vim

I have vim to add headers to my files and I want to change the minor version number automatically each time I do `:w` to save the file. The header line is like this:

```
# Version     : 0.0.24
```

and I know I need to add something like this

```
autocmd Bufwritepre,filewritepre *.* exe "1,". 10 . "g/Version ???<C-a>
```

to my .vimrc file. However, I can't get it right. Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you only have problem in `???` part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
....  g/Version/norm! $^A``
```

this cmd will increment the number, and keep the cursor position.

the `^A` you press `C-V C-A`

you also could turn to `:s/.../\=.../`  to increment the minor version part.

Comment: On my system (windows) it turned out to be `g/Verison/norm! $h <C-A>`
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @HamidR.Darabi: If it works for you, please [mark the answer as accepted.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235)